# Geoserver 2.8.1 Cluster Plugin Error

Tags: geoserver

I have tried to put cluster plugin in geoserver\WEB-INF\lib.whenever i tried to put those plugins,geoserver failed to load, but i remove those plugins from lib geoserver works.
Can anyone please help me..
i have attached the screenshots of plugin which i used.
[image]

Comment: are you using the same version of the jars as your version of GeoServer? what does the log file say?